# Ram usage increases when MediaPlayer switches songs (Monogame c#)

Tags: c#, xna, media-player, monogame

I'm making a game using the Monogame engine and I'm using MediaPlayer to play background music. When I switch whatever song is playing I can see the ram usage increase by several MB (using the 'Performance and Diagnostic Tool') even though it's a song that's been preloaded. After a lot of song changes this could become a problem. I want to make the game use as little of the computers resources as possible.

```
 Song song1;
 Song song2;

 protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            song1 = Content.Load<Song>("song1");
            song2 = Content.Load<Song>("song2");
         }

 void updateMusic()
        {
            if (gameState == "lvl1") { MediaPlayer.Play(song1); }
            else if (gameState == "lvl2") { MediaPlayer.Play(song2);}
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the current version of MonoGame I was using (3.5) is bugged and has some kind of memory management issue. After switching to MonoGame version 3.4, loading and unloading works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to unload the current song after changing to a new song if you don't want RAM usage to increase. Even if that isn't the issue, you should do that anyway if you are not planning on using that song again or anytime in the near future. And have you tested what happens if you do load a bunch of songs and switch between them? Just because you see a usage spike when switching between these two songs, doesn't necessarily mean that the usage will continue to stack as you switch between more songs.